# Find item in array and toggle values

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
tabs = [
  { id: "tabA", active: true },
  { id: "tabB", active: false },
  { id: "tabC", active: false }
];
```

How can I:
1. Given a tabId find if it is active?
2. Toggle the active value of all tags? So true > false and false > true.

Comment: So I am guessing for part 1, good old binary search on IDs is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate your array and find the object:

```
function findById(arr, id){
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i].id == id) return arr[i] // found, return the object
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

Then you can do:

```
//1
console.log(findById(tabs,'tabB').active)
//2 (individual tag)
var obj = findById(tabs,'tabB')
obj.active = !obj.active
//2 (all tags)
for(var i = 0;i < tabs.length;i++){
    tabs[i].active = !tabs[i].active
}
```

Comment: probably better if return null for findById and check obj before accessing it.

Comment: @Leng true, -1 is usually to find indexes. Changed ;)